# How to do math division in Blender 3D?

Tags: 3d, blender

I spent more time looking for an answer than the tutorial lasts. All I see on the internet is a subdivision surface, but I need to divide a number by a number. Using a standard slash, a unit is automatically put in a divisible number and there is no way to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean do the math while transform?

Numeric Input:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/numeric_input.html

Enable advanced numeric input in Preference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFJQk.png